# MySQLnd not loading

Tags: php, mysql, server

I have enabled the mysqlnd module in the backend of my webspace, but it doesn't work.

So I write a code which shows the mysqlnd status:

```
if (function_exists('mysqli_fetch_all')) {
    echo "mysqlnd enabled!"."<br>";
} else {
    echo "Not enabled"."<br>";
}

if(extension_loaded("mysqlnd")) {
    echo "loaded"."<br>";
} else {
    echo "not loaded"."<br>";
}
```

Strangely it returns:

```
Not enabled
loaded
```

So the module is loaded, but the functions aren't present. Anybody know why?

Comment: Probably because of your PHP version. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php (PHP 5 >= 5.3.0) - If you were to replace `mysqli_fetch_all` with either `mysqli_query` or `mysqli_fetch_array` you'll see that you may very well see your "enabled" message pop up. The manual states *"MySQL Native Driver Only"* in the manual.

Comment: However, your title "MySQLnd not loading" is a bit misleading. You state *"Strangely it returns:

Not enabled
loaded"* - which says that `mysqlnd` is loaded, just not the function.

Comment: I check other mysqlnd functions and they doesn't work. But why they doesn't work? I use PHP 5.6/5.5. The fetch all function was only an example to show, that the mysqlnd function doesn't work. I can also use get_result()

Comment: I couldn't say. I thought maybe your PHP version had something to do with it, but since you mention that you're using 5.6/5.5 then my theory's blown out of the water.

Comment: See what `phpinfo();` brings up.